# Why is my dir not showing in ftp session?

Tags: centos, ftp, user-permissions

I am new to linux so please have patience with me.

I set up my `centos 6.3` server on a virtual machine, installed many things including `httpd` and `vsftpd`.

I changed the config to allow only users in the `chroot_list` and the other settings are as usually recommended on the net.

I created a user `"adduser -d /var/www wwwftpuser"` then did a `passwd`.

I am able to connect to this now using an ftp client on my virtual machine host. But... the directory is blank. I tried uploading a file to it but the directory on the linux machine does not see the new file.

My aim is to upload and amend files in `/var/www` using ftp.

Why is this so?

Comment: Try changing the folder permissions to 755.

Comment: Better answered in the UNIX and Linux SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No thanks to the down voter, at least say why you down voted.

I found the answer eventually, there is something called `SELinux` that was blocking access to the chrooted directory.

So I did :

```
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

Which sorted the problem out, now I see the files. I am just testing so its ok for me but I do not recommend anyone does this if they do not know what it does.

Comment: For your convenience, if you're not running an environment which high security, you can just disable selinux entirely.

Comment: @Grumpy please could you tell me if it would be a good idea to disable SELinux if I fear a DDOS attack?

Comment: DDoS has little relationship to selinux.